# Как добавить товары из корзины Woocommerce в форму?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте есть форма, которая находится в корзине - [ссылка на сайт](https://bb-talkin.ru/korzina/). Как сделать так, чтобы данные из формы захватывали каталог товаров из корзины и отправляли вместе с данными уже имеющимися в форме на почту?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="kek" value="<?=$order?>">
```

Если товар находится в куки, то `$_COOKIE['order'];`

И далее значения отправляешь на почту в файле, куда все данные пришли